# Google Maps APIv3. Marker text changes style depending upon the text

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am adding markers to a google map from an array, all with the same style and two different font sizes. Two of the markers seem to be thinner than the rest with identical styles.

In the page below the markers 'Klong Kong' and 'Ban Thung' are thinner compared to the other markers of the same style/size. If I change the marker text e.g. 'Klong Kong' to 'Klong Kongx' it renders fine, seems specific marker text is causing my issue.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TEST MAP</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
        }
        body {
          font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: small;
          background: #fff;
        }
        #map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                window.onload = function () {
                    var options = {
                        zoom: 13,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.553697, 99.06302),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                    var textBig = '20';
                    var textSmall = '14';

                    var locations = [
                      ['Ban Saladan', 7.651093922, 99.03995, 1, textBig],
                      ['Klong Dao', 7.63408027, 99.0269495, 1, textBig],
                      ['Phra Ae', 7.612178, 99.031062, 1, textBig],
                      ['Klong Khong', 7.574728, 99.033068, 1, textBig],
                      ['Klong Toab', 7.565497, 99.040943, 1, textBig],
                      ['Klong Nin', 7.538923, 99.048078, 1, textBig],
                      ['Klong Hin', 7.519017, 99.058989, 1, textBig],
                      ['Ba Kantiang Bay', 7.49551, 99.074525, 1, textBig],
                      ['Nui Bay', 7.488632, 99.079278, 1, textSmall],
                      ['Klong Jaak Bay', 7.486043, 99.083451, 1, textSmall],
                      ['Mai Phai Bay', 7.480503, 99.088885, 1, textSmall],
                      ['Ban Thung', 7.63694, 99.111174, 1, textSmall],
                      ['Ban Loh Yai', 7.609017, 99.123346, 1, textSmall]
                    ]

                    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                        var location = locations[i];
                        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatLng,
                            map: map,
                            icon: 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=ffffff|' + location[4] + '|l|000000|b|' + location[0],
                            title: location[0],
                            zIndex: location[3]
                        });
                    }
                };
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```